# Python GIL, C extensions, and increasing through put (Python 3.2)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, gil

I have a server application that accepts requests, needs to run some Python, some of which calls into my C-based extension DLLs.  If I completely lock the GIL during the entire request, everything works fine.  But I'd like to release it while in the C-based extension DLL when long-ish operations are taking place so more requests can be processed.  This is my approach so far:

```
A. Request arrives on thread I don't control
B.   Call PyGILState_Ensure
C.      Call into Python runtime via PyRun_String  
D.          Python calls my MethodA in my C-based code
E.              Call PyGILState_Release 
F.                  Do long-ish processing
G.              Call PyGILState_Ensure to lock GIL again
H.          Return control to Python for further script processing
I.      Python runtime returns
J.   Call PyGILState_Release
```

All of the steps above are a single thread (and there are many similar threads in the system).

The call sequence above always throws an exception somewhere in step (H) deep in Python (which I can't seem to figure out from the stack trace).  However, if I make an extra call to PyGILState_Ensure at (B) so that the calls at (E) and (F) don't end up doing anything, everything runs perfectly.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?  I'd really like to release the GIL during lengthy operations so other requests can make progress.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right `PyGILState_STATE` at each step? In other words, you have to pass the one from `B` to the one at `E`, then store the one from `G` in a different variable that you pass to `J`. (Alternatively, you could make `E` and `G` into a `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`/`Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` pair.)

Comment: Also, can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead of pseudocode?

Comment: I'm using a per-thread PyGILState_STATE value, so it's the same variable for B, E, G and J

Comment: OK, that's a slightly different problem, which is equivalent to the first part of the solution that I offered—and which still has a serious problem that I didn't explain. The quick answer is still `ALLOW_THREADS`, but I'll edit my answer to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to match the `PyGILState_Ensure`/`PyGILState_Release` pairs at B and E, and G and J, rather than the more naively-obvious matching matching of B and J and E and G. (If you try it that way, step E releases an uninitialized state, corrupting the interpreter's internal state information.)

But you're using a single state, which doesn't have that problem. (I'm not actually sure this is legal, but I am pretty sure it's safe with every version of CPython, and there's definitely no way it could get things out of order.)

---

Unfortunately, this has a *different* problem. As the [`PyGILState_Release`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#PyGILState_Release) docs say, it:

> Release any resources previously acquired. After this call, Python’s state will be the same as it was prior to the corresponding `PyGILState_Ensure()` call…

In other words, you can't carry any interpreter resources across a `Release` and subsequent `Ensure` (unless they're protected by an outer `Ensure`, of course, but in that case you're not actually releasing anything).

So, as soon as you `Release` the state that was ensured for `PyRun_String`, the rest of that `PyRun_String` call becomes invalid. Switching to a newly-acquired state in the middle doesn't help.

---

But I think you're abusing `Ensure`/`Release` unnecessarily in the first place. You don't need to register the thread with the interpreter, unregister it, register it again, and unregister it again; all you need to do is release and reacquire the GIL from within the same thread. That's what [`Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/c-api/init.html#Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS) and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` are for.

As the documentation for [`PyGILState_Ensure`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/c-api/init.html#PyGILState_Ensure) says:

> In general, other thread-related APIs may be used between `PyGILState_Ensure()` and `PyGILState_Release()` calls as long as the thread state is restored to its previous state before the Release(). For example, normal usage of the `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macros is acceptable.

So:

```
PyGILState_STATE state;

B. state = PyGILState_Ensure();
    ...
E.              Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
F.                  Do long-ish processing
G.              Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    ...
J.  PyGILState_Release(state);
```

Comment: Maybe the ALLOW_THREADS is the best way to go.  I'm so used to critical sections that it seemed best to just lock when I needed it, not unlock when I'm sure I don't need it.

Comment: @DougN: Even though it's not really equivalent, think of it this way: you wouldn't do `LeaveCriticalSection(&cs); DeleteCriticalSection(&cs); … InitializeCriticalSection(&cs); EnterCriticalSection(&cs);` when you just wanted the `Leave`/`Enter` parts, right?

Comment: Ahhhh, that's the light bulb I needed to go on!  Thank you!